# Ubuntu 21.04 not showing wireless even though lshw lists it

Tags: drivers, wireless, 21.04, iwlwifi

I upgraded to 21.04 bc someone said it would solve it but had the same issue in 20.04. Wireless doesn't show at all in network settings "No Wi-Fi adapter found".

`lshw` does list it:

```
*-network
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 8265 / 8275
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
```

and `iwlwifi` files exist in `/lib/firmware/`

Laptop: Asus rog strix gl703vm

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: FYI: If you were using 20.04.3 LTS with the HWE stack, then upgrading to 21.04 will find the same stack (you'll have got a newer stack if you were using the GA kernel stack on 20.04).  Please note though Ubuntu 21.04 is in it's final days so upgrade to 21.10 asap.  refer https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-December/000275.html